How to browse image folders in flat view
I have a Windows 10 user who has a large number of pictures distributed across a folder tree on a Box drive.
He would like a faster way of seeing thumbnails than opening each folder and waiting for them to load.
I know of a Macintosh Application called "GraphicConverter" that has a file menu item "Browse Flat.." that allows you to select a folder and have all the subfolders shown in the one view. It fixes the speed problem by spawning a number of processes to load thumbnails from the folders.
We have been trying in both the Box web view and in Windows File Explorer but both suffer from a slow download of thumbnails.
Is there some way of replicating that on Windows 10?

Is this Box drive synced to Windows and you're talking about the File Explorer interface, or are you working in the Box client or webclient?

File Explorer's only trick for showing the contents of subfolders in a single window is the Search function, though that won't be fast, and you'll have the same thumbnail generation issues. Adjusting your thumbnail cache settings may help some.

I have added a note regarding Box and File Explorer. Where can I adjust thumbnail cache settings?
